# google analytics v3 catch all exceptions

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to catch all exceptions and have report them meaningfully in google analytics. What I have done so far is :

set `<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>`, I guess this is working only for the activities that easytracker enabled like this: `EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);`

I wanted to catch all exceptions in application level, and easyTracker to also keep working in defined activites.

I have tried to modify this v2 solution into v3, but still not seeing my exception in google analytics(http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-analytics-easytracker-detailed.html)

```
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = new ExceptionReporter( 
    easyTracker, // Tracker, may return null if not yet initialized.
    GAServiceManager.getInstance(),                        // GAServiceManager singleton.
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), this); 

exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());

UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler =  exceptionReporter;       // Current default uncaught exception handler.

// Make myHandler the new default uncaught exception handler.
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.To get exception report in google analytics**
 Use this function in your global file

```
 public static void sendExceptiontoServer(Context mContext,String title, Exception e){
     try{
         EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(mContext);
         easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createException(
                 new StandardExceptionParser(mContext, null)
                 .getDescription(title + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName(), e), false).build());
     }catch(Exception ex){
     }
 }
```

And call this function from anywhere in your code as

```
      try{ 
}catch(Exception e){ 
 GlobalFile.sendExceptiontoServer(mContext, "error description :", e); 
}
```

**2. To get crash report** 
copy-paste this code in **Oncreate** function of your Application class

```
 EasyTracker.getInstance(this).set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, getClass().getSimpleName());

Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
if (uncaughtExceptionHandler instanceof ExceptionReporter) {
  ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = (ExceptionReporter) uncaughtExceptionHandler;
  exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());
}
```

And create AnalyticsExceptionParser class as

```
 public class AnalyticsExceptionParser implements ExceptionParser {
            @Override
            public String getDescription(String thread, Throwable throwable) {
           return String.format("Thread: %s, Exception: %s", thread,Log.getStackTraceString(throwable));
               }
           }
```

Comment: how to use in android app. i used this in my catch condition like this myTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
     .setDescription(
       new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
         .getDescription(Thread.currentThread()
           .getName(), e)).setFatal(false)
     .build());

Comment: @VijayRajput Didn't get you.

Comment: how to use in android app activity

Comment: @VijayRajput Which code? you posted in comment,please explain more in detail,and post as a new question will be useful.

Comment: how to use this AnalyticsExceptionParser class in setdescription method in above comment code

Comment: @VijayRajput I used AnalyticsExceptionParser  for crash report,and for your need you may call sendExceptiontoServer in catch block.

Comment: @VijayRajput You may use myTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder() .setDescription(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());

Comment: @VijayRajput Happy to help,enjoy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57911/discussion-between-vijay-rajput-and-giru-bhai).

Comment: How does Android know to make the uncaughtExceptionHandler an instance of the ExceptionReporter?